# google compute engine disk auto resizing, without reboot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

Windows Server is running as GCE VM.
I wonder if there is a way to automatically expand disk without rebooting.

For example, if the total capacity of the disk is 250 GB, when the disk is used about 230 GB, it automatically becomes 300 GB and I want to operate the service without rebooting without interruption.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase disk size without rebooting, you can find the command [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/resize).
Basically, it's `gcloud compute disks resize <DISK_NAME> --size <SIZE_IN_GB>`

However, **this does not increase partition size** automatically. If it's boot partition you want to increase, you may have to reboot your machine.

Alternatively, you can take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) and create a new, bigger disk that can be attached to your VM or used as a boot disk for a new VM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate answer.!!! Was very helpful!